# Android MediaPlayer is not calling registered listener

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have implemented a MediaPlayer instance in order to reproduce a single file (mp3 format, actually I did not try with other formats).
I created the instance of MediaPlayer in a custom class extending Handler. I use this class in a foreground service.
Everything is operating correctly, besides the callback to listeners.

I tried to create a listener instance and pass it to setOnCompletionListener() method, I tried using an anonymous class. Eventually, I tried to set the listeners after the player is started the first time as suggested in other posts.

This is the code I used in my last try: the listener is registered before calling the player `start()` method.

```
    public ServiceHandler(Looper looper, Context context) {
        super(looper);
        this.context=context;
        goPlay=true;
    }

    public void stopWorking(){
        goPlay=false;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        reproducing=false;
        prepared=false;
        registered =false;

        mp=new MediaPlayer();
        if(mp!=null){
            Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.aledev.mygoat/" + R.raw.goat);
            try {
                mp.setDataSource(context, path);
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        Log.d("onCompletion","onCompletion called.");
                        AudioManager audio=(AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                        audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,oldVolume,0);

                        reproducing=false;
                        Log.d("onCompletion","onCompletion Finished.");
                    }
                });
/*              mp.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        prepared=true;
                    }
                });*/
                mp.setWakeMode(context.getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
                //mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mp.setLooping(false);
                mp.prepareAsync();
            }
            catch(java.io.IOException ex){
                Log.d("handleMessage","URI not correct.");
            }
        }
    ...

        while(goPlay){

            if (Math.abs(accelVal - oldAccelVal) > ACCEL_DELTA) {
                //if((!reproducing)&&(prepared)){
                if ((!reproducing)) {
                    AudioManager audio = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    oldVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);
                    reproducing = true;
                    mp.start();
                }
            }
            oldAccelVal = accelVal;
        }
        manager.unregisterListener(this);
        if(mp!=null) {
            mp.release();
        }
        Log.d("handleMessage","Thread: "+this.getLooper().getThread().isInterrupted());
    }
```

I expect that, the boolean flag reproducing is set to false, but this does not happens.
Howerver, looking to logcat MediaPlayer playback completion is detected and onCompletion event is fired.

```
2019-07-24 11:23:55.911 15466-15487/com.aledev.mygoat V/MediaPlayerNative: 
playback complete
2019-07-24 11:23:55.911 15466-15487/com.aledev.mygoat V/MediaPlayerNative: 
callback application
2019-07-24 11:23:55.911 15466-15487/com.aledev.mygoat V/MediaPlayerNative: 
back from callback
```

What else can I try in order to get the callback working?

Comment: Uncomment `onErrorListener` and see if you get an error, playback was complete but complete can mean both complete with error or complete successfully.

Comment: @Zohaib Amir:I uncommented the listener, but it is never called. Again, MediaPlayer reports playback is completed and callback is called.

Comment: @Zohaib Amir: However, my listener is not trigger (neither onCompletion nor onError).

Answer (score 1):

I solved my specific problem entering a while loop conditioned by isPlaying() method of MediaPlayer.

I am still not able to have listeners callbacks managed.